# passing a '-9' to xargs kill command

Tags: rhel, kill, xargs

I'm writing a script to stop an application. Sometimes the application doesn't want to stop. So after a several minute pause, if the application is still running I want to kill it. After a number of failures of the kill command, I tried adding the -9 to force stop it. This doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I can get this to function, even if I need to use a different command, I'm open to new things. :-)

Following is my command line:

`ps -ef|grep -v grep|grep <process_name>|awk -F' ' '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me this entire pipeline can be reduced to: `pkill -9 <process_name>`

Comment: `grep -v grep | grep «process_name»` could be done better as `grep «[p]rocess_name»`. (and if you did have to do it the first way then swapping the order would be more efficient.)

Comment: what does `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep «process_name» | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'` return? What about `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep «process_name»` ?

Comment: @richard and it will still be as useless as `cat /path/file | grep xpto`. `pkill -9 <procname> ` should be enough...

Comment: @nwildner I understand all of the words (except xpto), but I have no idea what you are saying. Something will still be as useless as something, but what I do not know. Please help, by re-writing comment.

Comment: forgot that `xpto`. I has a meaning on Brazilian Portuguese. Take that as `foo`. What i was trying to say is that,  `cat`+`grep` combination is useless, the same way @Noobux question could be solved with `pkill` as said by @muru... making all that combination to "take a process name and kill it" not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To clarify, the `<process_name>` was meant as a placeholder for a unique string that would identify the process I wanted. The actual string is `Dcatalina.home`. The whole statement `ps -ef|grep -v grep|grep Dcatalina.home|awk -F' ' '{print $2}'` returns the PID which is piped to the `xargs kill` command.

Comment: Got timed out on my previous comment. Here's the rest...
I am unfamiliar with `pgrep` and `pkill`. When I tried `pgrep Dcatalina.home` and I tried with single and double quoting the search term, it returns nothing and `pkill` failed as well. However, many thanks to @muru and @Deathgrip. The `pkill -9 -f Dcatalina.home` command works like a charm!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@muru was correct, but lately I've found that using the '-f' option to pkill is preferred. Matches against the entire process and argument list. Here we have a few servers running Tomcat processes and Logstash (sending data to Elastic). So 'kill -9 java' to stop the Tomcat process also kills the Logstash process.

```
pkill -9 -f 'pattern to match'
```

Example:

```
pkill -9 -f '/opt/tomcat/'
```

Answer (score 9):

Example how to close `php` processes in batch. `php` you can replace using whatever your process has name:

```
ps -aux | grep php | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: The point made in a number of the comments and summarised nicely by the accepted answer is that such a pipeline is totally unnecessary. Even without `pkill` one can do `ps -aux | awk '$11 ~ /[p]hp/ {print $2}' | xargs kill`

Comment: Bear in mind that the only signal that every process is forced to obey is the **KILL** signal. The result of rest of the signals it depends on how such a program was coded.